# How create a generic Array to add any view

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Are There any way to add all views?

```
        View.Add(textFieldUser);
        View.Add(textFieldPassword);
        View.Add(buttonLogin);
```

that way is very lazzy, i want add with a function and array

```
public void add(UIViewController v, T[] arr){
    for(view in arr[i]){
      v.Add(view)
    }
}
```

its possible?

Comment: Why not? Did you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you wrote is perfectly acceptable, however if you are looking for the convenience of calling the method on the actual UIViewController objec then you can create your own extension method to do the same.

```
public static class UIViewControllerExtensions
{
    public static void AddRange(this UIViewController v, params UIView[] arr){
        for(view in arr[i]){
          v.Add(view)
        }
    }
}
```

which can then be called as:

```
View.AddRange(textFieldUser, textFieldPassword, buttonLogin);
```

Or as:

```
var views = new UIView[] 
{
    textFieldUser, 
    textFieldPassword, 
    buttonLogin
}
View.AddRange(views)
```